# Scraping youtube comments using selenium and google colab is slow

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, google-colaboratory

I am using selenium and google Colab to scrape video comments from YouTube. It takes about an hour to go through the scraping process, whether it's 1000 comments or 38 comments. Is there something I can do to improve my code to increase the processing speed? Thank you!

Acknowledgement to the following sources which helped to build the code.
1: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GFJKhpOju_WLAgiVPCzCGTBVGMkyAjtk#scrollTo=4Ylzd_l6fXGv
2: https://www.tfzx.net/article/2719742.html
3: https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-python-8a60f4cf40ab

Output #1:

```
Completed scraping 1000 comments in 3089.1585 seconds from YouTube Entertainment Tonight channel.
```

Output #2:

```
Completed scraping 38 comments in 3011.5525 seconds from YouTube Anne Schmidt channel.
```

Input:

```
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
%pip install selenium
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

def scrapecomments(url):
  tic = time.perf_counter()
  wait = WebDriverWait(wd,15)
  wd.get(url)
  data1=[]
  data2=[]
  data3=[]
  for item in range(200): 
          wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,                "body"))).send_keys(Keys.END)
          time.sleep(15)
  for author in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#author-text"))):
    if len(data1) == 1000:
      break
    else:
      data1.append(author.text)
  for comment in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content-text"))):
          data2.append(comment.text)
  for likes in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#vote-count-middle"))):
          data3.append(likes.text)

  def merge(list1, list2, list3):
    merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i], list3[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))] 
    return merged_list
  
  alldata = merge(data1,data2,data3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  comments = pd.DataFrame(alldata,columns=['user_id','comment','likes'])
  comments['rank'] = comments.reset_index().index +1
  channel_name = wd.find_element_by_id('channel-name').text
  comments['source'] = channel_name
  toc = time.perf_counter()
  print(f"Completed scraping {len(data1)} comments in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds from YouTube {channel_name} channel.")
  return comments
```

Comment: Don't use time.sleep(15).

Answer (score 0):

Might also be that you're installing chromedriver and selenium every time you run the code

Comment: Thanks @Maxiboi! I am running the installation codes separately. Do you mean removing "wd.get(url)" outside of the def function?

Comment: Yeah, that might help as well